# Is it possible to configure SSL and non-SSL sites on the same Apache server?

Tags: apache-http-server, ubuntu-16.04

Let's say I have domain1.com, domain2.com and domain3.com running on the same Apache web server using just one public IP address. The site domain2.com will implement an SSL certificate, but domain1.com and domain3.com won't.

Which one could be the best practice in order to configure Apache in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to configure SSL and non-SSL sites on the same Apache server?

Yes.

> Let's say I have *domain1.com*, *domain2.com* and *domain3.com* running on the same Apache web server using just one public IP address. The site *domain2.com* will implement an SSL certificate, but *domain1.com* and *domain3.com* won't.

This is fine. You should be safe in making *domain2.com* your only SSL host.

For your non-https sites, you can configure them as normal. The only "extra" step I might consider would be making a non-HTTPS version of *domain2.com* to automatically redirect HTTP traffic to the HTTPS version of the site (assuming this is desirable behavior).

If you are interested, here is the basic [Ubuntu 16.04 Apache2 documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/httpd.html) (which contains some minor but relevant notes regarding SSL under "HTTPS Configuration") and a just slightly more detailed [SSL tutorial for Ubuntu 17.04](https://websiteforstudents.com/setting-ssltls-apache2-ubuntu-17-04/).

As a small caveat, the links above deal primarily with self-signed certificates. Since you are on Linux, you may wish to check out [CertBot](https://certbot.eff.org/). Certbot allows you obtain valid public certificates from [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) and uses some automation to help ease the management of those certificates.

---

*For Windows, the relevant SSL default configuration file is typically `conf\extra\httpd-ssl.conf`. Likewise, [ZeroSSL](https://zerossl.com/) provides a good command line tool for Let's Encrypt (though it isn't automated).*

---